# MySQL/MariaDB/SQLite: DISTINCT CONCAT

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, sqlite

This question isn't necessarily just Laravel related, but I'm trying to fetch records, which are distinct by concatenated fields. I need this to work with both `MySQL/MariaDB` as well as `SQLite` for testing purposes.

While doing my research, I've found out that `SQLite` does not have `CONCAT` function - instead you're using `||` operator to concatenate items. `MySQL` on the other hand will not interpret `||` the same way, but I can always use the conditional statement just to cover both cases.

However, I still cannot get records I'm after - my table consists of:

```
| id | tagable_id | tagable_type       | name | title | description | url               | image                | hits |
| 1  | 1          | App\Models\Article | a..  | A..   | A.. descr.. | https://localhost | https://localhost... | 0    |
| 2  | 1          | App\Models\Article | b..  | B..   | B.. descr.. | https://localhost | https://localhost... | 2    |
| 3  | 1          | App\Models\Article | c..  | C..   | C.. descr.. | https://localhost | https://localhost... | 3    |
| 4  | 1          | App\Models\Page    | a..  | A..   | C.. descr.. | https://localhost | https://localhost... | 0    |
```

I need get only 4 records that are sorted ASC by number of hits and which are unique using `CONCAT(table_id, tagable_type)`.

What the statement should return in this case would be records with id `1` and `4` - because `2` and `3` have the same `tagable_id` and `tagable_type` as record with id `1`, which has lowest number of hits - effectively only returning only 2 records:

```
| id | tagable_id | tagable_type       | name | title | description | url               | image                | hits |
| 1  | 1          | App\Models\Article | a..  | A..   | A.. descr.. | https://localhost | https://localhost... | 0    |    
| 4  | 1          | App\Models\Page    | a..  | A..   | C.. descr.. | https://localhost | https://localhost... | 0    |
```

I tried already:

```
DB::table('tags')
->selectRaw("DISTINCT CONCAT(`tagable_id`, '-', `tagable_type`), `id`, `name`, `title`, `description`, `url`, `image`")
->whereIn('name', $tags->toArray())
->orderBy('hits');
```

This however does not return distinct records - it will return all records regardless of the distinct concatenation - that is in MySQL / MariaDB - in SQLite it will tell me `no such function: CONCAT`.

I also tried:

```
DB::table('tags')
->selectRaw("CONCAT(`tagable_id`, '-', `tagable_type`) as `identifier`, `id`, `name`, `title`, `description`, `url`, `image`")
->whereIn('name', $tags->toArray())
->groupBy('identifier')
->orderBy('hits');
```

This time MySQL/MariaDB tells me that I need to include other fields in the group by as well `tags.id' isn't in GROUP BY`, but when I use it with SQLite and replace `CONCAT` function with `(tagable_id || '-' || tagable_type) as identifier` - it seem to work.

So at this stage I'm: `MySQL: 0 | SQLite: 1`

Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE**
After hours of trying to get it resolved I've decided to add a new column 
 `identifier` to the table to overcome issue of the non available `concat` function - my code now looks like this:

```
Tag::with('tagable')->whereIn('id', function($query) use ($tags) {
    $query->selectRaw('min(`id`) from `tags`')
        ->whereIn('name', $tags->toArray())
        ->groupBy('identifier');
})
->orderBy('hits')
->take(4)
->get();
```

This is still not quite what I'm after as it relies on the lowest id `min(id)` of the given identifier and if the record with the lowest id for the same identifier has higher number of hits then its sibling then the sibling will not be returned.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expcted  result

Comment: Just added example data and explanation of what should be returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DISTINCT` to get distinct combinations, but not whole rows:

```
DB::table('tags')->distinct()->get(['tagable_id', 'tagable_type']);
```

You have to use a more complex query for that:

```
$join = DB::table('tags')
    ->select('tagable_id', 'tagable_type')->selectRaw('MIN(hits) as hits')
    ->whereIn('name', $tags->toArray())
    ->groupBy('tagable_id', 'tagable_type');
$sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') as grouped';
$tags = DB::table('tags')
    ->join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
        $join->on('tags.tagable_id', '=', 'grouped.tagable_id')
            ->on('tags.tagable_type', '=', 'grouped.tagable_type')
            ->on('tags.hits', '=', 'grouped.hits');
    })->mergeBindings($join)
    ->whereIn('name', $tags->toArray())
    ->get();
```

A solution that guarantees one record per unique combination:

```
$join = DB::table('tags')
    ->select('tagable_id', 'tagable_type')->selectRaw('MIN(hits) as hits')
    ->whereIn('name', $tags->toArray())
    ->groupBy('tagable_id', 'tagable_type');
$sql = '(' . $join->toSql() . ') as grouped';
$ids = DB::table('tags')
    ->selectRaw('MIN(id) as id')
    ->join(DB::raw($sql), function($join) {
        $join->on('tags.tagable_id', '=', 'grouped.tagable_id')
            ->on('tags.tagable_type', '=', 'grouped.tagable_type')
            ->on('tags.hits', '=', 'grouped.hits');
    })->mergeBindings($join)
    ->whereIn('name', $tags->toArray())
    ->groupBy('tags.tagable_id', 'tags.tagable_type')
    ->pluck('id');
$tags = DB::table('tags')->whereIn('id', $ids)->get();
```

Comment: Thanks - how will this behave in the situation where records of the same `tagable_type` and `tagable_id` have the same number of hits - i.e. `0`? I believe it will return multiple records of the same `tagable` type as `join` is connected via those 3 fields, which might have the same values for multiple records.

Comment: Yes, in that case it will return multiple records. Do you need the query to return only one record?

Comment: No - I need number of records, which I specify using `take` method, but each record needs to represent unique combination of `tagable_id` and `tagable_type`. I've now even added an extra column to store value representing concatenation of both of these fields - to remove the issue with SQLite not supporting `concat`, but I still cannot figure out how to get unique records by this concatenated field.

Comment: I added a solution to my answer that guarantees one record per unique combination by using the lowest id when multiple records have the same number of hits.

Comment: Thanks @Jonas - appreciate your time. It looks like it will require 3 database queries, which I would prefer to avoid. I've been playing with it for most of the day and came up with a single query solution, which only partially resolves the problem - so not quite what I'm after - I've updated the question.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? It's possible to merge it into one query, if that is a concern.

Comment: Yes - it does work - thanks very much. I'll accept this answer.

Comment: There is still however discrepancy between MySQL and SQLite - it works with MySQL, but SQLite seem to return just one random record.